# MySQL trigger with 2 queries

Tags: sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to make a trigger to a certain table that makes it so that when I insert data into that table, two other tables are updated. I am trying to do something like this, on the trigger section of phpMyAdmin:

```
INSERT INTO db.tableOne (id, name, country) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.country);

INSERT INTO db.tableTwo (id, colour, price) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.colour, NEW.price);
```

It gives me a syntax error.

I tried creating 2 different triggers for the same action on that table but it says that I can't have 2 triggers for the same action. Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Ok, solved. For anyone who has the same problem, it's quite easy actually: just put a "BEGIN" statement before the "INSERT" statements, and a "END" statement after.

Comment: You should select the 'Solve/Answer your own question' option and put your comment in there.  Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, solved. For anyone who has the same problem, it's quite easy actually: just put a "BEGIN" statement before the "INSERT" statements, and a "END" statement after.